# How to manage a file which should be explicitely merged?

Tags: svn, merge

I've two file which need to be different in my development environment (local repository, development branches, pre_production branch, ...) and in my production one's.

But I still need to activate subversion on them. What is the recommended way to manage them? I would like not to be asked to merge them when I re-intrgrate pre_production branche into the production one.